# How to configure d2.xlarge linux instance on AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vps

I am planning to buy d2.xlarge instance from the AWS

[image: d2.xlarge]

Here I can get 3 hard drive of 2000 GB each.

But when I am trying to launch the instance, I am getting there storage volumes already created for me as part of the d2.xlarge plan.

But I can not use any of those volumes as root to install my operating system on them and if I increase the limit of EBS beyond 30GB then I will be charged extra so those 3 hard drives will be of no use for me.

[image: Volumes on step 4]

This are the volumes already created by aws.
How to change root and use one of those volume to install my OS.

Comment: When you launch an EC2 instance, you select an Amazon Machine Image (AMI). That AMI includes a pre-installed OS. You don't install your own OS on top of that. You could, potentially, import a machine image from OVA/VMDK or other using VM Import/Export.

Comment: You can delete those 3 hard drives if they will be of no use for you. Just click on the "x" on the right.

Comment: Not using the `d2` drives means that you're effectively paying $0.69/hour for an `r3.xlarge` instance (which costs $0.333/hour).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the point of the `d2` instance types: the attached volumes are intended for storage, not for use as your root volume. This is a standard Linux practice: a small root partition that contains the OS and any additional applications, with mounted volumes for application data (historically, `/usr` was a separate mounted volume, and `/home` often is on multi-user installations today).

As example use cases, you could use a group of `d2` instances to create a Kafka cluster that will be processing a large amount of data, or as the data nodes in an HDFS cluster.

Beware however, that these volumes are *ephemeral*: if the instance ever shuts down you will lose their contents. Therefore, *only* use `d2` instance types for applications (like HDFS) where you have redundant storage and can afford to lose an instance. *Do not* use them for things like databases or sole-source application data or you *will* be unhappy (I've personally experienced unexpected shutdowns on two `d2` instances that were used as part of a Kafka cluster -- in that case it didn't matter because we were heavily redundant).

In my opinion, it is generally a better idea to use EBS storage. It will be more expensive, but the volumes have a lifetime separate from the instance (so if you lose an instance you can attach the volume to a different one).

Also remember that the `d2` instance types use physical hard drives, so you will be limited in the number of random IOPS.

Answer (score 1):

1. The AWS instance comes pres-installed with linux. You do not have to install the OS. Choose the distro (Ubuntu, RedHat etc..,) before launching the instance.
2. The **Instance Store** is a **temporary storage** whose contents will disappear when you stop the instance. You can optionally delete them and not use them. See: [Amazon EC2 Instance Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html)
3. Click on Add New Volume and add a volume of up to 2000 GB. Choose the type of volume you would like to add.
4. You can add up to 3 such volumes.
5. You do not have to add 2000GB volumes when you launch. Launch it with mimum required (like 250GB) and expand it when needed without stopping the instance.

**Adding 3 New Volumes**
[image: Adding 3 New Volumes]

**Adding 3 New Volumes with Instance Store deleted and expand root to 100GB**
[image: Adding 3 New Volumes with Instance Store deleted]

Answer (score 0):

```
/dev/sda11 will be the root volume.
```

If you already launched vm , just goto volume page identifie the volumes which are not required through the volume_id which can find in instance description.

```
stop VM first then detach the vloume and delete it.

start the vm and you will end up with only root volume.
```

Else launch vm using AMI and in add-storage page remove those extra volumes and increase the root volume as you needed.